# Finite Values Error produced when simulated Generalized Extreme Values distribution to find MSE RMSE and bias

Tags: r, optimization, statistics

I am working on Generalized Extreme Value Distribution in R and I want to calculate the bias, mse and rmse of the disitribtion. However when I'm using the mle function the following error occured.

```
Error in optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, lower = lower,  : 
  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
In addition: Warning message:
In optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, lower = lower,  :
  bounds can only be used with method L-BFGS-B (or Brent)
```

The code is as following:

```
library(stats4)
library(evd)
gev_simulation<-function(N,n,location,scale,shape){
  conc<-numeric(N)
  for(i in 1:N){
    samples=rgev(n,loc=20.3379490,scale=12.6009604,shape=shape)
    gevlik<-function(location,scale,shape){
      -sum(dgev(x=samples,loc=location,scale=scale,shape=shape,log=TRUE))
    }
    result<-mle(minuslogl=gevlik,start=list(location=20.3379490,scale=12.6009604,shape=0.1),method="BFGS")
    conc[i]<-result@coef
  }
  conc
}

summarygev1<-function(conc){
  bias=mean(conc)-3;bias
  mse=var(conc)+bias^2;mse
  rmse=sqrt(var(conc)+bias^2);rmse
  return(c(bias,mse,rmse))
}

simulate20<-gev_simulation(1000,20,20.3379490,12.6009604,0.1);simulate20
summarygev1(simulate20)
```

This error will not occured in like 1 out of 10 times, is there something wrong is the randomization of my code?

I try setting the lower limit of all parameter to 0.1 but it still not working